# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: kor]
[image: kor]
[image: kor]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congratulations to all! We need to note that two members of the Pro Tem have not contributed so much to the site so far. I can judge it based on the number of their posts on Meta, their votes on both main board and Meta, and edits so far, let alone frequency of their visits to the site.  I hope they will contribute to the site more than they did in the past and really volunteer their time to make Korean SE successful. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I have given my daughter and my cat to a neighbor to raise as their own in order to devote my undivided and otherwise unemployed attention to all necessary details of the site. We need not fear.

Comment: @Vladhagen good luck to you, and also to our site :-)

Comment: @Vladhagen I don't think you need to spend more than 10 minutes a day for your moderator job for the next 5 years unless Korean SE is swamped with more questions. As far as I can expect based on other language sites such as Chinese, Spanish, your job will only be limited to cleaning up the mess, especially spam and offensive or rude posts and comments. The more important thing is your participation (asking and answering), voting. and monitoring the quality of posts.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to all! As I commented, I don't think you'll need to spend more than 10 minutes a day (maybe less than 5 minutes would suffice) to serve as a moderator on this site as we have only about one question per day nowadays and I don't expect it will increase dramatically for the next few years as I mentioned in this linked answer.

[Our site is turning into a ghost town. Thoughts on Why?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/our-site-is-turning-into-a-ghost-town-thoughts-on-why/83#83)

I believe your moderating jobs will be limited to the following tasks for the time being:

> (1) delete spam, offensive or rude posts and comments (I don't think there will be many and they have been well taken care of so far).
>
> (2) take care of flags (I don't think it will be an everyday event).
>
> (3) monitoring unconstructive comments (You need to get yourself
> familiarized with the [Moderator
> Tools](https://korean.stackexchange.com/tools) and move them to a chat
> if necessary).
>
> (4) close questions as unclear, general reference, duplicate, etc. (We
> need to have clear policy on this. As far as I remember, we have
> closed just two question which means there won't be many to close
> in the future).
>
> etc.

**With great power comes with great responsibility.**

I think Korean SE has been well managed so far without any moderator involved with remarkable 100.**00**% questions answered. No other SE sites have this perfect percentage except for Russian Language SE. I am confident that the quality of Korean SE is excellent thanks to all the efforts spent by some dedicated members.

I want you to participate more in asking and answering questions. As a non-native Korean speaker, you have better chance of asking thought-provoking and interesting questions. The number of posts and votes will tell other users how much you are contributing to this site.

Also, please start to discuss some policies that will guide Korean SE better. You can visit other language sites and see how their moderators are working and what policies they are proposing and debating.

**I hope you will all lead us by example. Good luck to you all.**

Comment: It's great that it's all been so friendly so far. I am hoping that none of the mods (especially me) will get too distracted by 'modding' and still be able to focus on learning Korean and helping others. Thanks once more for your immense answer record Rathony - if we can really stay at the top of the 'percentage answered' league, that would be quite something!

Comment: @topomorto Focusing on learning Korean and helping others is the key, I think. Look at the sheer number of unanswered questions on [Latin SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). Wow, at least Korean SE doesn't have a single question unanswered. In order to keep this record, we need to improve the quality of the questions. We are at the top of the percentage answered. We will continue to be. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to all of you guys :). Now we have a speedy way to kill spam.