# A step forward towards building our stack exchange site

Tags: discussion

Our site has completed 90 days in beta
Stackexchange recently [appointed moderators for our site](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) including myself
I would like to congratulate the other moderators as well as promise to do my part in helping build our community
More importantly, I hope this means our stackexchange site is growing steadily and we will be able to reach our goal of creating an effective Q and A site for discussion on Korean language

I also welcome all the new users and ask everyone to have a good time using this site

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem Korean SE is facing now seems to be there are not many avid users.

> Korean SE has only 35 users with 200+ rep, 3 users with 2,000+ rep, and only
>   1 user with 3,000+ rep. The recommendation says they should be 150,
>   10, 5 respectively.

I think all of the moderators nominated yesterday are candidates for 3,000+ rep users and in order to cross that mark, you need to ask and answer more questions.

The more avid users Korean SE has, the more questions, answers and visits per day the site will have.

It would be better if we could make more efforts to increase the answer ratio from 1.8 to 2.5. It means we should not hesitate to post an answer to already answered questions as long as it can add more value to the existing answer(s).

Comment: Although I think our proportional-to-user-count beta metrics are in rather good shape, I do agree that we need a higher answer ratio. I'm not sure if we actually need 2.5, maybe 2.2/2.3 would be fine for our site's age, but having such a target is always helpful :-)

Answer (score 3):

Although this little community has always been great, there was some truth in your [ghost town](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/our-site-is-turning-into-a-ghost-town-thoughts-on-why) post. A month or so later, visits per day are now nearer 100 than the fifties, we have a better mix of people asking questions, and as you say, having mods is another great milestone! Things like busukxuan's [metric charts](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/beta-metric-charts) are great to see too, and Rathony has pointed out that we are doing fantastically well when it comes to percentage of questions answered:

[image]

This is in no small part due to that same user's efforts:

[image]

A public thanks for that, and thanks again user17915♦ for proposing this site and your fantastic efforts getting others to commit!

I am always in favour of "be nice" being guiding principle #1. There will also be value in making sure we exemplify all the usual strengths of stack exchange : good organisation, clear questions, accurate answers, and a generally nice and tidy site.

Comment: [There are other sites with 100% questions answered](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered), but all their numbers are rounded up except for Russian Language. Other sites like Worldbuilding, Puzzling, Russian Language, The Workplace, Spanish Language, Parenting, Role Playing Games all have unanswered questions. :-)