# How can we promote the beta?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This site is great and seems to be slowly gaining popularity, but still [needs work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language). How can we get the word out more so there are more users and more activity? Related questions have been [asked](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/our-site-is-turning-into-a-ghost-town-thoughts-on-why) before, but nothing the hits directly on promotion (usually they focus on quality, which is also important, but we also need more users and overall traffic). So, two questions:

- What have we done so far to promote this site?
- What can we do to promote this site? (both as a whole and as individuals)

*I hope brainstorming questions like this are ok on meta.*

Comment: Looks like you posted our 1000th answer - 축하합니다!

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this earlier. I have a long [list of site promotion ideas](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/800) over at Language Learning Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

**Community Promotion Adverts**

Graduated sites show little promotion advertisements in the right-hand panel of their front page. Every year a question is put onto the site's meta asking which other sites should be promoted and how. The highest voted adverts on that question get shown.  Using these would spread the existence of the site around the wider StackExchange community.

An example site on which we could publish would be [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3431/4376).  The reason being that many users there are native Koreans who could be of benefit to this site.

It would be useful to promote on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) too.  However, that is a beta site, so can't show such adverts.

We need to put together a little promo or two and post them as answers on a target site's meta question.

Comment: This would be great! I'm kind of curious if we actually have that many English language learners on this site. I would think not, but I could be wrong. I'm going to add some comments below for other potential sites and people can vote them.

Comment: Candidate Site: [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Candidate Site: [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Candidate Site: [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Candidate Site: [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Candidate Site: [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Candidate Site: [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: About the idea of creating community ads on the sites above, I have got the impression that generally they don't like it and consider it sort of spammy, even on sites like Japanese and travelling, where one would expect this site would get some level of support. So I doubt sites for English, puzzling or academia will take kindly to it (but then again, you never know; maybe someone who is more established on those sites should have a look if this site would get more support there)

Comment: One of our helpful users had made a community ad for the site during beta in [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/community-promotion-ads-2015/3299#3299). At one point it did get the minimum number of votes needed to be displayed as a community ad. but only for a short period of time, and going through the meta and chats of other SE sites I've generally found it to be unwelcomed.

Comment: It is true that if you suggest a community promotion ad on an unrelated site then it will almost certainly fail to get approved.  However, I would have thought that other language sites would be supportive.

Answer (score 4):

**Word of Mouth**

The Korean learning community is somewhat small, but I think everyone knows a handful of people in our own networks we could tell about the site. Examples:

- Korean classes
- Korean teachers/professors
- Language exchange partners/groups
- Social media
- Blogs
- Libraries
- Other Korean learning related sites

This is a bit hard to manage as a whole, but if every user tried to make an effort to let people (especially people who might be outside of the SE community) about this site, it could really improve our reach.

Comment: Great suggestion. One person I pointed to the site said that it seemed a 'bit advanced' - so a take away from that might be that we want to do our best to deal well with beginner questions where they are a fit for the site.

Answer (score 1):

I know our honorable founder user17915♦ did a lot to promote the site as it was in its definition and commitment phase - I think some posts on https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/ helped?

The 'selling point' of this site, as I see it, should be that it's an easily-searchable database of well-written, clear questions about the Korean language, with well-written, clear answers. I think that's still needed on the web; Other sites that have great user-bases don't seem to have the infrastructure that keeps the questions visible and searchable, and encourages people to keep improving the answers.

So though not a direct answer to our question, one thing that we can do is make sure we build on that by

- Asking any interesting questions that occur to us during the course of our Korean learning, even if we already got an answer from our teacher / wife, etc. (Our questions per day doesn't seem to be increasing as much as our visits per day). We are already getting a lot of our traffic from search engines, so our content seems to correlate to things that people are searching for. The more good content we have, the more search hits we'll get!
- Using all our moderation abilities to keep the site tidy - copy-editing, keeping an eye out for duplicate questions, etc.
- And of course, answering where we are able!

In terms of direct promotion, one small thing I think we can do to promote the site in an honest way is to link to good questions here from other sites - e.g. if someone has a good, specific question on Reddit that already has an answer here. Hopefully that won't be seen as a subversion on reddit - that site has many strengths and allows many types of questions that wouldn't really work so well here.

I'll add any more ideas if I have them.

I do think it may be better in the long run for us to grow steadily and organically - so that there's always a good ration of active experienced users to active new users. A *sudden* influx of new users might be a bit tricky! But we definitely want to get to the point where every Korean learner knows this site and what it's for.

Comment: Focusing on quality of course is important, but even if we have a perfectly curated site, it doesn't mean much if we don't have the traffic. As a relatively active Korean learner, I was surprised I didn't know about this site -- and I'm sure there are a lot more people like me. I really don't think there are enough Korean learners in the world to cause too big of a sudden influx, but I hear you. Even if we did get a bunch of new people, the SE reputation system should kick in and do it's job :)

Comment: @ryanbrainard Yes, it would definitely be good to increase traffic. I was picking up on questions per day as something we also want to work on because as you can see from https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/beta-metric-charts, QPD hasn't really increased at the same rate as traffic has.

Comment: @another thing is that a lot of our page hits do already come from search engines, so interesting content should translate into more hits (added note in my post above).

Comment: wow, those graphs are amazing, and show that overall we are steadily improving, but yes, our QPD is lagging. Word-of-mouth outreach to places like Korean classes could probably help with that by saying something like, "Have a question about Korean and don't want to wait until the next class? Just ask on Korean.SE." Good point about search engine traffic as well (although where are you seeing that?).

Comment: @ryanbrainard Yep good job from busukxuan. Search engine traffic is visible on the moderator's toolbar... it comes with a warning not to share the specific data, but I hope it's ok for me to say that the bulk of our page hits originate from search engines.  So good content really should drive traffic - we then want that to also drive participation to complete the circle.